# How to map content of a file to an exisiting dictionary c#

Tags: c#, file, dictionary, mapping

So, what I am trying to do is to map the content of two different files based on a unique item, the "sampleName" in this case. The content of one of the files was added to a dictionary earlier, this contains a list with properties and a sampleName as key.

This sample name also occurs in the second file which has the following format:

```
*Projectnummer;Datum;wetenschappelijke_naam;zakje;ring;klantnr         
"aNumber";"aDate";"scientificName";"123456";"12";"aNumber" etc..*
```

Where "123456" is the sampleName, this also occurs in the previous made dictionary.

**The problem** here is that with the current code the wrong items are added to the wrong sampleCode within the dictionary(correctSamplesDict). The adding of information does not happen based on matching sample numbers but on the order of the lines within a file.

**How** can I check wether sample names match and thus which information needs to be added?

```
try
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            bool headerCollected = false;

            int projectNumberId = -1;
            int dateId = -1;
            int scientificNameId = -1;
            int sampleNameId = -1;
            int ringId = -1;
            int customerIdId = -1;

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
            while (reader.Peek() > 4)
            {
                Sample sample = new Sample();
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                line = line.Replace("\"" , string.Empty);
                string[] lineParts = line.Split((char)59);
                switch (headerCollected)
                {
                    case false:
                        if (line.ToUpper().Contains("PROJECTNUMMER"))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < lineParts.Length; i ++)
                            {
                                if (lineParts[i].ToUpper().Trim().Contains("DATUM")) { dateId = i; }
                                if (lineParts[i].ToUpper().Trim().Contains("WETENSCHAPPELIJKE_NAAM")) { scientificNameId = i; }
                                if (lineParts[i].ToUpper().Trim().Contains("ZAKJE")) { sampleNameId = i; }
                                if (lineParts[i].ToUpper().Trim().Contains("RING")) {ringId = i; }
                                if (lineParts[i].ToUpper().Trim().Contains("KLANTNR")) { customerIdId = i; }
                                if (lineParts[i].ToUpper().Trim().Contains("PROJECTNUMMER")) { projectNumberId = i; }

                            }
                            headerCollected = true;
                        }

                        break;
                    case true:


                        if (dateId != -1 && lineParts.Length > dateId) { sample.ProjectDate = lineParts[dateId].Trim(); }
                        if (sampleNameId != -1 && lineParts.Length > sampleNameId) { sample.SampleName = lineParts[sampleNameId].Trim(); }
                        if (customerIdId != -1 && lineParts.Length > customerIdId) { int.TryParse(lineParts[customerIdId].Trim(), out sample.CustomerNumber); }
                        if (projectNumberId != -1 && lineParts.Length > projectNumberId) { sample.ProjectNumber = lineParts[projectNumberId].Trim(); }
                        if (ringId != -1 && lineParts.Length > ringId) { sample.RingNumber = lineParts[ringId].Trim(); }
                        if (scientificNameId != -1 && lineParts.Length > scientificNameId) { sample.ScientificName = lineParts[scientificNameId].Trim(); }

                        List<Sample> sampleProperties = null;
                        Sample sampleVal = null;

                        if (correctSamplesDict.TryGetValue(sample.SampleName, out sampleProperties))
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Sample>> items in correctSamplesDict)
                            {
                                foreach (Sample sampleValue in items.Value)
                                {
                                        // initializes a new object for each iteration
                                        sampleVal = new Sample();
                                        sampleProperties = new List<Sample>();

                                        // These values still are correct                                   sampleVal.HeightOne = sampleValue.HeightOne;
                                        sampleVal.HeightTwo = sampleValue.HeightTwo;
                                        sampleVal.SizeOne = sampleValue.SizeOne;
                                        sampleVal.SizeTwo = sampleValue.SizeTwo;
                                        sampleVal.SampleName = sampleValue.SampleName;

                                        // mapping goes wrong here (wrong sample information to the wrong sampleName)
                                        sampleVal.ProjectDate = sample.ProjectDate;
                                        sampleVal.ProjectNumber = sample.ProjectNumber;
                                        sampleVal.CustomerNumber = sample.CustomerNumber;
                                        sampleVal.RingNumber = sample.RingNumber;
                                        sampleVal.ScientificName = sample.ScientificName;
                                        sampleProperties.Add(sampleVal);
                                    }                                                                                      
                            }
                            correctSamplesDict[sampleVal.SampleName] = sampleProperties;
                        }


                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Edit**
The sample file looks like this:
Sample_Name    Size1    Size2    Height1    Height2

```
SampleName: SizeOne:    SizeTwo:    HeightOne:  HeightTwo:  
123 364 368 8921    8550
456 367 0   8948    0
789 367 0   9475    0
```

Comment: can you share sample file which you read @user3309936?

Comment: the sample you are giving does not clear you logic you implemented in the code. Still unclear

Comment: The content of the first sample file is implemented in another part of code and saved within a dictionary. The sample I am reading in this part has a format as explained in my question. With a header which looks like: Projectnummer;Datum;wetenschappelijke_naam;zakje(sampleNumber);ring;klantnr . And that header has all information. I am not quite sure if I understand what you would like to know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things seem odd in your code :

- You are using a **switch/case** on a boolean variable, instead of an **if/else**
- You are using a `Dictionary<string, List<<Sample>>` to store your data, when you could have only use a `Dictionary<string, Sample>` (from what I understand).

Apart from this, your problem comes from this part of your code :

```
if (correctSamplesDict.TryGetValue(sample.SampleName, out sampleProperties))
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Sample>> items in correctSamplesDict)
    {
        foreach (Sample sampleValue in items.Value)
        {
            //skip...
        }
    }
    correctSamplesDict[sampleVal.SampleName] = sampleProperties;
}
```

where you should do this

```
if (correctSamplesDict.TryGetValue(sample.SampleName, out sampleProperties))
{
    foreach (Sample sampleValue in sampleProperties)
    {
        sampleValue.ProjectDate = sample.ProjectDate;
        sampleValue.ProjectNumber = sample.ProjectNumber;
        sampleValue.CustomerNumber = sample.CustomerNumber;
        sampleValue.RingNumber = sample.RingNumber;
        sampleValue.ScientificName = sample.ScientificName;
    }
}
```

You don't even have to replace the list in your dictionary as you are now setting data directly inside them.